# How to count occurences of an int in an array?

Tags: c#, arrays

My array is `A = {2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4}`

I need an array B that stock at the index `i` the number of occurences of `i` in the array A.

I want a code which return:

```
b[2] = 3
b[3] = 2
b[4] = 4
```

Keep in mind if any number adds in above array `A` should also add in resultant array `B`.

I will be very thankful if someone help me in this.

Below given my code which I have done so far.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int [] A = new int[4];
        int [] B = new int [A.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i > A.Length; i++)
        {
            B[A[i]] = B[i];
        }

    }
```

I am new to the programming. I got this scenario to write an algorithm and I am writing this type of algorithm first time.

Comment: You haven't write any algorithm here. It is just your desired input and output - and there is no any logic how to get output from input. So I really doubt someone can help you in this since there are no mindreaders here.

Comment: Thats not an algorithm, thats just grouping things by how many are in the list

Comment: An algorithm is just a series of steps to reach a desired output, so yes, this is an algorithm (when it works)

Comment: Any limits on the ints? What if one of the ints in the `a` array is `2,147,483,647`? `b` array would need to 8GB in size! Or `-1`, that would be impossible to use as index.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to find out how *many time each item presents in the*, say, *array*, 
you can use *Linq*:

```
  int[] a = new int[] 
   { 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4 };

  // I'd rather not used array, as you suggested, but dictionary 
  Dictionary<int, int> b = a
    .GroupBy(item => item)
    .ToDictionary(item => item.Key, item => item.Count());

 ...

the outcome is

  b[2] == 3;
  b[3] == 2;
  b[4] == 4;
```

Comment: Actually I first tried to give this approach but deleted my answer since OP is too new :) But it seems this is the easy way..

Comment: Dictionary is the only solution that isn't affected by the values in the array `a`. They can be large numbers, or negative.

Answer (score 2):

Your task can be easily accomplished using a [Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Here is the code :

```
 Dictionary<int, int> ItemCount = new Dictionary<int, int>();

 int[] items = { 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4 };

 foreach (int item in items)
 {
    if (ItemCount.ContainsKey(item))
    {
         ItemCount[item]++;
    }
    else {
        ItemCount.Add(item,1);
    }
 }

  Console.WriteLine("A|B");
  foreach (KeyValuePair<int,int> res in ItemCount)
  {
      Console.WriteLine(res.Key +"|"+res.Value);
  }
```

output :

```
A  |   B
2  |   3
3  |   3
4  |   4
```

Note : I think this might be too advance for you , but it's an easy way

Without Dictionary, (A primitive approach)

```
     int[] A = { 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4 };
     List<int> B = new List<int>(); // <= We need this to check already counted numbers in array

     int temp = 0; // <= A temporary variable to get a count per a specific elemet
     int count = 0; // < = Will hold number of elements we have already counted 

     Console.WriteLine("A|B");

     for (int i = 0; i < A.Length; i++)
     {
         temp = 0;

         // Check for a fresh number 
         if (!B.Contains(A[i]))
         {
             B.Add(A[i]);
             // For each element we try to count the number of occurrence 
             for (int j = 0; j < A.Length; j++)
             {
                 // Current element i matched with a element in array; counts increased 
                 if (A[i] == A[j])
                 {
                        temp++; // < = Local count
                        count++; // <= Kind of the global count of elements we have passed
                 }
             }

                Console.WriteLine(A[i] + "|" + temp); 
            }

           // We need to do this only for unique elements; when we have counted all elements in Array A we are done
           if (count >= A.Length)
           {
                break;
           }

      }
```

Comment: yes thanks  KcDoD it is working but can someone suggest me any other way without using dictionary? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: @kamran Ladhani yes check the new answer :)

Comment: Thank you so much KcDoD. I got what I wanted :) Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @kamran Ladhani Welcome :) mark the answer as correct it solved or is the best solution ;) Also you can upvote answers which you think are usefull

Comment: Note that the Dictionary isn't orderd by key (use SortedDictionary for that) Try changing int[] items = { 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 } and see

Comment: A good point ..but may  OP doesn't need that ;) And simply a random array which gave his output in ordered fashion..

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a homework or a tutorial. You have good solutions in Linq, but here is a simple version with basic algorithm:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int [] A = new int[4];
    // you should determine the size of B dynamically here...
    // Try to find yourself!
    int [] B = new int[999];

    /*  Code forgotten : initialize array B to 0s */

    for (int i = 0; i < A.Length; i++)
    {
        int item = A[i];
        // increase the number at index item
        B[item]++;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for number of occurences, I have made some examples, still I'm  not really sure what do you mean by saying if you add arrays in A they should appear in B. To have this kind of funcionality you have to use some notification framework and cannot have simple arrays. At the very least you should wrap all functions where you want to add an element to A and make calculation like i have showed in third example (with result array E).

```
            int[] a = new int[] { 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4 };

        //version 1 - unsorted array
        //find top number of A array
        int max_number_a = a.Max() + 1;
        //initialize B,C of that size
        int[] b = new int[max_number_a];    //RESULT linq version
        int[] c = new int[max_number_a];    //RESULT double loop version
        for (int i = 0; i < max_number_a; i++)
        {
            //this is linq way
            b[i] = a.Where(x => x == i).Count();

            //this is double loop way
            c[i] = 0;           //initialize position so we can later count/increment when we find each instance of i inside A array
            for (int j = 0; j < a.Length; j++)
            {
                if (a[j] == i)   //check if a[j] is the number we are searching for
                    c[i]++;      //we have found one instance of J number, increase the B[i]
            }
        }

        //version 2 - sorted array
        int[] d = new int[max_number_a];    //RESULT sorted array
        //initialize all to zero
        for (int i = 0; i < max_number_a; i++) d[i] = 0;        //initialize array to zeros so we can count
        List<int> aList = a.OrderBy(x => x).ToList();            //this is linq ordering, choose any other way to order it
        while (aList.Count > 0)                                 // we have to use all a elements
        {
            d[aList[0]]++;
            aList.RemoveAt(0);
        }            

        //version 3 - the simple (right) way, and probably what you should be doing :)
        int[] e = new int[max_number_a];
        //initialize all to zero
        for (int i = 0; i < max_number_a; i++) e[i] = 0;        //initialize array to zeros so we can count
        for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
        {
            //we take e index of a[i] and increments its value
            e[a[i]]++;                             
            /*
             * int number_in_a = a[i];
             * int e_index_value = e[number_in_a];
             * e[number_in_a] = e_index_value + 1;
             */
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/yWgedG)

Or if you don't fancy clicking the link:

```
var a = new int[]{2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4};
var b = new int[a.Length];

    var aAsList = a.ToList();

    for (var i = 0;i < b.Length; i++)
    {
        var result = aAsList.Count(x=> x == i);
        b[i] = result;

        if (result != 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("b[{0}] : {1}",i,result));
        }
    }
```